# Adding a webpart to the right of New Form

Tags: list, web-part, newform

I have a list that is used to schedule certain tasks for employees.  To make it easier to know the schedule of specific employees, I would like to add the calendar view of that list to the New Form page.  I haven't been able to find a concrete way of doing this, below is an example of what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried editing the NewForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: I am not 100% no how I would float the calendar to the right

Comment: You have to learn CSS then : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necro, but I recently had the same problem and I wanted to share my solution for future explorers. Navigate to the form in SharePoint Designer and make a copy of your form so you don't break the original. Open the copy in advanced mode by right-clicking on it and selecting "Edit in Advanced Mode". The webpart zones are formatted as a table on the page, in this case a table with one column. What you want to do is add another column to this table and put your webpart zone in it.Find the `</td>` tag and just below it, insert the following code:

`<td><WebpartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Right" Title="loc:Right"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebpartPages:WebPartZone></td>`

Then from the ribbon click "preview in browser". You should see the extra webpartzone on the right side of the original.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a Calendar view to your Task list, then your tasklist will be like this

[image]

then you'll be able to select this view from "Edit webpart"

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm deleting my original answer because I found another way to do this.
In SharePoint Designer, bring up the EditForm, for example.
You should see a button to edit in advanced mode. Not sure if you have to select the ListFormWebPart first or not.

In any case, eventually you'll see in the ribbon a tab for "Web Part Zone Tools' Format. 
There is a Zone Layout button, where you can change the zone to be horizontal. 
Select that, save, then when you go into the form to add your new webpart, it will be to the right or the left, instead of above/below.